# Rings of polynomials with very high amount of variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ a commutative ring. We can create the polynomial ring with uncountably many variables $R[\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}]$. However, it seems like anything we do on this ring could be done on the smaller ring, with just countably many variables $R[\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}]$, since ring operations act on a finite number of elements and any element of these rings uses only a finite number of variables.

Are there any interesting properties that one of these rings have that the other doesn't, other than cardinality?